# Spatial Cross Correlation between two rasters

Tags: r, correlation, focal-statistics

I have two raster data land cover and carbon monoxide, and I wish to perform correlation analysis on the two datasets. I found an [article online describing the method using RStudio](https://%20statnmap.com/2018-01-27-spatial-correlation-between-rasters). I have followed the procedure and gotten the section where I need to perform local correlation using the focal function then then create an output raster from the results. But I keep getting error messages.

How can I make this code work without any error? Below is the code and error message I have been getting.

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(terra)

# Loading data
land_use <- raster(file.path("lulc_2021.tif"))
air_data <- raster(file.path("gio_co.tif"))

# Res-sampling the data
Resam <- resample(land_use, air_data, method = 'bilinear')

# Masking the data
land_use_m <- mask(land_use, air_data)
air_data_m <- mask(air_data, land_use)

# Plotting the data
plot(land_use_m)
plot(air_data_m)

# Overlaying the two Raster.
overlay <- stack(land_use_m, air_data_m)
plot(overlay)
overlay_o <- sampleRegular(overlay, 1000)
overlay_o <- data.frame(na.omit(values(overlay)))
names(overlay_o) <- c("land_cover_change", "air_quality")
#print(overlay_o)

# correletation test.
cor(overlay_o[,1], overlay_o[,2])
print(cor.test(overlay_o[,1], overlay_o[,2]))

# linear test 
#linear <- lm(overlay_o[,1] ~ overlay_o[,2], data = overlay_o)
#summary(linear)

# plotting focal correlation
local_cor <- rast(overlay, 1)
values(local_cor) <- 1:ncell(overlay)

matrix_over <- values(overlay) 

directory <- "~/Correlation_Analysis/spatial_cross_correlation" #"." 

# suppress warning "the standard deviation is zero"
suppressWarnings(focal_cor <- focalCor(local_cor, w=5, cor))

focal_cor <- focal(
  x = local_cor,
  w = matrix(1, 5, 5),
  
  fun <- function(x, y = matrix_over){
    cor(y[x, 1], y[x, 2],
        use = "na.or.complete")
  },
  
  #filename = file.path(directory, "focal_cor.tif"), 
  #overwrite = TRUE
)

local_cor <- writeRaster(focal_cor, filename = file.path(directory, "focal_cor.tif"), 
                         format = "GTiff", overwtite = TRUE)

corre <- raster(file.path(directory, "focal_cor.tif"))
plot(corre)


Error Messages.
So the first error message i got is from trying to write the output raster of the focal_cor variable within the function it self as seen in the script above
> focal_cor <- focal(
+   x = local_cor,
+   w = matrix(1, 5, 5),
+   
+   fun <- function(x, y = matrix_over){
+     cor(y[x, 1], y[x, 2],
+         use = "na.or.complete")
+   },
+   
+   filename = file.path(directory, "focal_cor.tif"), 
+   overwrite = TRUE
+ )
--------Called from: cor(y[x, 1], y[x, 2], use = "na.or.complete")
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Browse[1]> 
> #local_cor <- writeRaster(focal_cor, filename = file.path(directory, "focal_cor.tif"), 
>                          #format = "GTiff", overwtite = TRUE)
> 
> corre <- raster(file.path(directory, "focal_cor.tif"))
> plot(corre)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': object 'corre' not found


The second error message is when i tried to write the output correlation in a new variable 
focal_cor <- focal(
+   x = local_cor,
+   w = matrix(1, 5, 5),
+   
+   fun <- function(x, y = matrix_over){
+     cor(y[x, 1], y[x, 2],
+         use = "na.or.complete")
+   },
+   
+   #filename = file.path(directory, "focal_cor.tif"), 
+   #overwrite = TRUE
+ )
Error in .local(x, ...) : argument is missing, with no default
> 
> local_cor <- writeRaster(focal_cor, filename = file.path(directory, "focal_cor.tif"), 
+                          format = "GTiff", overwtite = TRUE)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'writeRaster': object 'focal_cor' not found
> 
> corre <- raster(file.path(directory, "focal_cor.tif"))
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
> plot(corre)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': object 'corre' not found
>
```

Comment: Since you explicitly mention a paper linking to it could provide further context for people trying to answer your question since they're going to see what the expected output should look like.

Comment: As @Vincé said, you should provide a link to the article you mention. Until then, if I understand correctly, you want to perform local correlation. Here is the function to do that using the package `terra` (https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/focalCor.html)

Comment: Hey @Vincé please fine attached the link to the article I have been using 
https://statnmap.com/2018-01-27-spatial-correlation-between-rasters/